# Invoking from a thread works but can't be done simpler?

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I managed to make a simple program that updates a TextBox from a different thread and class. The most simple way to learn threading in a visual way. ;)

The code is made with the documentation from msdn. It runs and I see no memory leak. But I have a feeling this can be done simpler.

There are two main classes; the Form and a BackGround class. In the BackGround class is a function called generateStream that updates a TextBox in the Form class via a delegate to a function called updateTextBox.

When buttonStart is pressed there are two actions performed. First generateStream is called directly. When generateStream is ready a thread is made that runs generateStream again (via TheFunction). When using a different thread, TextBox requires a invoke solution.

All this is implemented and works. I think it's quite a lot of code and can perhaps be done more clean.

The function in the mainclass that updates the form and is called back.

```
public void updateTextBox(string strtext)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired) //When calling from another thread; invoke is required.
        {
            SetTextCallBack cb = new SetTextCallBack(updateTextBox);
            this.Invoke(cb, new object[] { strtext });

        }
        else //Call can be performed safely.
        {
            textBoxStatus.SelectionStart = textBoxStatus.Text.Length;
            textBoxStatus.AppendText(strtext);
            textBoxStatus.Update();
        }
    }
```

The actions done by the click of the button.

```
    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonStart.Enabled = false;

        /*
         * Step 1: Let's call the function blocking.
         *          The GUI will not respond to mouse geastures. Hoover mouse over inputbox to see no change in pointer.
         */
        bg.generateStream(numberOfCalls, "GUI Thread: ");


        /*
         * Step 2: Let's call the function in a seperate thread.
         *          The GUI will now respond to the mouse. Hoover mouse over inputbox to see pointer change.
         */
        Thread sepThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.TheFunction));
        sepThread.Start();

        buttonStart.Enabled = true;
    }
```

The generateStream function in the BackGround class.

```
    public void generateStream(int amountOfStreams, string inpString)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfStreams; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //Easy does it.
            myCallBack(inpString + i.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine); //This is the text to the Main Form.
        }
    }
```

When using a thread I use now two callbacks to update the TextBox. One from the BackGround class to the Form, and one to implement Invoke. Is there for instance no semaphore-solution possible that my updateTextBox function can have only one thread access?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question is, can you try to reword your last paragraph to better explain what your question is.

Comment: You're right it was too much text and no direction.

Comment: As a tip, your main question `I think it's quite a lot of code and can perhaps be done more clean.` should be put at the bottom of the post instead of the middle so it can be easily found too.

Comment: I highly recommend the article "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". Your final question `Is there for instance no semaphore-solution possible that my updateTextBox function can have only one thread access?` goes against [Describe the goal, not the step](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal). That statement I highlighted in my last comment is a perfect example of 'Goal not step'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no harm in calling Invoke when InvokeRequired is true.  I also like to use anonymous methods in C# 2.0.  You can simplify your function as follows:

```
private delegate void SimpleProc();
private void updateTextBox(string strtext) {
    this.Invoke(new SimpleProc(delegate() {
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
        textBox1.AppendText(strtext);
        textBox1.Update(); // only needed if updateTextBox is called from UI thread
    }), null);
}
```

Replacing Invoke with BeginInvoke is useful for a fire-and-forget scenario, where you don't want the background thread to wait for the UI thread to complete the update, but you need to be sure if this is OK for your application.

The updated function can be directly called from either the UI thread or your background thread.  No callbacks are needed; the only callback used is the anonymous function inside of updateTextBox.  It really doesn't get any simpler than this.  In fact, it's simple enough that the need for creating a separate function for invoking the UI thread is not necessary in many cases.

Comment: Thanks!

That already saves the need of an if statements and makes it simpler.

The only price I pay is that always an extra callback is being performed.

I was thinking about something like semaphores. But untill now I only find invoking as the proper way to handle this.

Comment: Actually, if you make the call from a UI thread, Invoke will essentially do what your original code did, which is directly call your callback without posting any message to the message queue.  The performance impact in that case is negligible; Invoke involves only a few extra function calls and code under the covers.  I would guess that the code in the callback that actually updates the UI takes far more time.  If you call Invoke from a worker thread, a custom window message is posted to the message queue, to be handled by the UI thread at some point in the future.